# How to create an array of custom class type, each containing the class?

Tags: c++

I would like to implement a matrix class named "Matrice", using a custom vector class named "Vecteur", by using a vector "Vecteur" of pointers, and defining each element of the "Vecteur" as a "Vecteur".

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "test.h"



using namespace std;
Vecteur::Vecteur(int m_dim=1)
{
    dim = m_dim;
    tab= new float [m_dim];
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++){
        tab[i]=1.0;
    }
}
Vecteur::~Vecteur(){
    delete [] tab;
}
Matrice::Matrice(int m_l, int m_c)
{
//  
    dims[0] = m_l; //lignes
    dims[1] = m_c; //Colonnes
//  
    mat = new Vecteur [dims[1]];
//
//
    for(int i=0;i<dims[1];i++){

        mat[i]= *new Vecteur (dims[0]);
    }
//
}
//
Matrice::~Matrice()
{
   delete [] mat;
}
```

**

test.h

```
#ifndef DEF_TEST
#define DEF_TEST

#include <iostream>

class Vecteur
{
    public:

    Vecteur(int m_dim);
    ~Vecteur();

    private:

    float *tab;
    int dim;
};

class Matrice
{
    public: 

    Matrice(int m_l, int m_c);
    ~Matrice();

    private:

    Vecteur * mat;
    int dims[2];
};

#endif
```

My problem lies in this line  **mat[i]= *new Vecteur (dims[0]);**, i have a pointer on the left and on the right, it is not a pointer, it is the value of the pointer, how can it work ?

Comment: It means that you leak a lot of memory. You allocate a `Vecteur` on the heap, dereference the pointer, copy the `Vecteur` object and discard the pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it is better to just remove ***new** ? And thanks for your answer

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `mat` is a `Vecteur*`, so `mat[i]` is a `Vecteur`. No syntactic problem there.